# Was Sailor Moon (Usagi) supposed to be seen as a "rich girl"?

Tags: sailor-moon

Sailor Moon apparently lives in the "Azabu-Jūban" district in Tokyo.

In the show (I'm talking about the first season of the original anime from ~1992), she is shown living in a stand-alone *house* in the middle of skyscrapers.

I'm not sure if that's a thing in reality, or if it was made up for the show because it's much nicer and more practical to show a family in a proper house as opposed to somewhere up in a crammed apartment.

But according to at least one native Japanese live streamer which I've interacted with, that district is apparently a "fancy" area where rich people live. I can't determine whether this is true or not, even after looking around with a "Street View" service.

Is the character in the show, "Usagi", supposed to be a rich girl? Everything else about her appears to be intended to portray a very "average" girl, who is clumsy and absent-minded and silly and whatnot. She also seems to have a normal family. Yet she lives in a relatively fancy house in the middle of Tokyo. Seems like that would cost a fortune.

Yes, I know that there are also supernatural demons and talking moon-cats, but I'm still very much wondering about this particular choice. It's been bugging me for a long time.

Comment: Toradora also has someone poor living in a house with a skyscraper next to it. If the house came first, the people in the skyscraper are rich and the ones in the house aren't.

Comment: I'd be a bit careful about applying the stereotypes of apartments to anime.  Depending on the place and the space, it could be a better option in somewhere like Tokyo.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer seems to be no, you don't have to think Usagi's family is (overly) rich.

Summarizing from [here](https://tokyo-calendar.jp/article/12332?page=2):

- Azabu juuban at that time was kind of middle of nowhere (considering the central location) because the metro lines [Namboku line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Metro_Namboku_Line) or [Oedo line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toei_%C5%8Cedo_Line) didn't exist yet.
- The choice is mainly because the author lived there once.
- During [Japanese bubble from late 80s to early 90s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_asset_price_bubble), it flourished by the proximity to Roppongi (which is also in Minato-ku).

Although it's uncertain when exactly the author lived there, most probably it was before the bubble (or at least before the bubble inflating too much), so the place was most probably a 'normal' (enough) place as imagined by the author.

At the same time, it is known that [the author](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A6%E5%86%85%E7%9B%B4%E5%AD%90) is from a rich family (she had a Porsche when *Sailor Moon* **began**), so probably there's some influence of that.

---

I don't know too well, but even in those fancy areas (you are correct about that in 2020s), there should be houses lived by people who have been living there since (perhaps) before the war, but to buy a new one would be ridiculously expensive (if it's possible at all).